# How to get an 'nth-of-type' in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium Webdriver to check the text of this particular paragraph (the one highlighted in blue here):

[image]

But how do I 'query' that paragraph?

This is what I'm trying (not working):

```
    def test_intro_text(self):
       """Test that intro text is expected text"""
       container = self.browser.find_element_by_id('visual-17')
       hed_dek_wrapper = container.find_element_by_class_name('hed-dek-wrapper')
       intro_text = hed_dek_wrapper.findElement('p:nth-of-type(2)')
       self.assertIn(
        'Over the past 20 years, we have seen an evolution.',
        intro_text.text
       )
```

I'm getting this error: AttributeError: `'WebElement' object has no attribute 'findElement'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findElement()` is not a Python. Try below instead:

```
intro_text = hed_dek_wrapper.find_element_by_css_selector('p:nth-of-type(2)')
assert 'Over the past 20 years, we have seen an evolution.' in intro_text.text
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this css selector for doing this :

```
#visual-7 .hed-dek-wrapper >p:nth-of-type(2)
```

and find element using css selector and it will give you the second p tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#visual-7 .hed-dek-wrapper >p:nth-of-type(2)");
```